# How to get matched string in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

Um..I'm not a java developer, but I'm editing a java plugin.

So.. basically, this plugin matches ^(/$)|(/cn/(.*)+$) pattern and redirect to a user.

The following is code snippet from the plugin.

```
if(uriPattern != null) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(uriPattern); 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(request.getRequestURI());
    matcher.find();
    matchURI = matcher.matches();


}

if (matchURI && redirectTool.shouldRedirectRequest()) {
    //do something
}
```

as you see, the pattern matches either / or /cn/[EVERYTHING] url. How do I get empty string when / is matched and cn when /cn/[EVERYTHING] is matched?

I tried matcher.group(), matcher.start(), and matcher.end()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matcher.group(1)` is `/` when your first subpattern matches, `matcher.group(2)` is `/cn/whatever` when your second subpattern matches.

And you don't seem to need the `+` and nested parens. I'd write your expression simpler: `^(/$)|(/cn/.*$)`